# How does zeta of zero equal to negative one half rather than to infinity?

Tags: number-theory, divergent-series, regularization

$$\zeta(0)=(1/1^0)+(1/2^0)+(1/3^0)+(1/4^0)+(1/5^0)...$$
Am I right?

Anything raised to the power of zero is one.
One to the power of zero is one.
One divided by one is one.
$$1/1^0=1$$
Am I right?

$$2^0=1$$
$$1/1=1$$
$$1/2^0=1$$
Am I right?

$$3^0=1$$
$$1/1=1$$
$$1/3^0=1$$
Am I right?

$$4^0=1$$
$$1/1=1$$
$$1/4^0=1$$
Am I right?

$$5^0=1$$
$$1/1=1$$
$$1/5^0=1$$
Am I right?

$$1+1+1+1+1...=\infty$$
Am I right?

Is $\zeta(0)$ not equal to $(1/1^0)+(1/2^0)+(1/3^0)+(1/4^0)+(1/5^0)...$?

My question is, just how does one compute $\zeta(0)$ to get $-1/2$?

Comment: It's a fine question but I find the presentation a bit grating. Do you honestly need confirmation that $1/k^0 = 1$ for various positive integer $k$?

Comment: The whole $\zeta$ function is just a (unique 'nice') *extension* of the originally given formula. Obviously, if you put $0$ in that formula, you will get $\infty$. However, in that unique extension, we get $\zeta(0)=-1/2$.

Comment: Such approach is true but note that for value n=0 we have analytic continuation of zeta function. We also have the value of 
$\zeta (-1)=1+2+3+...$ and $\zeta(-1)=-\frac{1}{12}$ That way we assign a finite value to an infinite result

Comment: The answer to your first question is "no". Read about analytic continuation.

Comment: $\zeta(0) \ne (1/1^0) + (1/2^0) + (1/3^0) + (1/4^0) + (1/5^0) + \dotsb$

Comment: Got it!  Very enlightening.

Comment: You are wrong when you write zeta (0) as a series (which is divergent anyway).The definition of the function zeta(s) as the sum of the series with general term 1/n^s is valid only in the region of convergence, i.e. Re(s) >1. The "functional equation" allows to extend analytically this function to C\{1} (there is a simple pole at s = 1), but this extension is not given by a series .

Comment: When a series diverges we can use various method to sum it to a finite result anyway. Search about "summability theory" "summation methods" and "regularization/renormalization" and you'll have a lot of fun.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a calculation. 
The Riemann formula is 
$$\zeta(s)=2^s\pi^{s-1}\sin\big(\frac{\pi s}{2}\big)\Gamma(1-s)\zeta(1-s)$$
We take the limit of this as $s\to 0$ and we use the fact that $s\zeta(1-s)\to -1$ as $s\to 0$, along with the fact that $\Gamma(1) = 1$.
Furthermore, $\sin(\frac{\pi s}{2}) = \frac{\sin(\pi s/2)}{\pi s/2}\frac{\pi s}{2}$, and $\frac{\sin (\pi s/2)}{\pi s / 2} \to 1$ as $s \to 0$. 
Putting it all together gives you
$$\zeta(0) = \lim_{s\to 0}\, 2^{s-1} \pi^s \cdot \frac{\sin(\pi s/2)}{\pi s/2} \cdot \Gamma(1-s) \cdot s\zeta(1-s) = 2^{-1} \pi^0 \cdot 1 \cdot \Gamma(1) \cdot (-1) = -\frac{1}{2}.$$

Answer (score 1):

When you have a divergent series, there are ways to give it a "meaningful" finite answer anyways. One way is by using the Ramanujan summation. All of the ways of assigning values to divergent series don't tell you that they don't diverge; they simply do a partial sum (or other method). This example is using the Ramanujan summation:

Zander 6-13-19 (don't mind this, I just like to label my stuff with the date)

$ \begin{array}{l}
\zeta ( 0) =\sum ^{\infty }_{n=1}( 1) =\infty ,\ but\ with\ the\ ramanujan\ summation\\
\\
Ramanujan\ summation\\
\boxed{\sum\limits ^{\infty }_{n=1} f( n)\overset{\Re }{=} -\frac{f( 0)}{2} +i\int\limits ^{\infty }_{0}\frac{f( ix) -f( -ix)}{e^{2\pi x} -1} dx} \Longrightarrow \\
f( n) =1\\
\\
\zeta ( 0) =\sum ^{\infty }_{n=1}( 1)\overset{\Re }{=} -\frac{1}{2} +i\int\limits ^{\infty }_{0}\frac{1-1}{e^{2\pi x} -1} dx=-\frac{1}{2} +i\int\limits ^{\infty }_{0} 0dx=-\frac{1}{2}\\
\therefore \zeta ( 0) =-\frac{1}{2} \Re 
\end{array}$

The $\displaystyle \Re $ means that it is only equal to that value, because the Ramanujan summation assigned it

that value. The Ramanujan summation should not normally (if ever, I'm not sure) be used on a

convergent series, it is a method of analytic continuation if the sumagrand (function in the infinite series) has an appropriate growth pattern. Also, just because this (and other stuff too) says it is $-1/2$, it still equals +infinity. But we define it differently with
analytic continuation.

It's more like saying that zeta of zero equals $-1/2$ rather than the infinite sum.

Comment: The Ramanujan summation is the most complicated [summation method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergent_series), you should avoid it whenever it is possible