How is $\zeta(0)$ actually $-1/2?$
I was searching around the forum, and I came across: $$\zeta(0) = \lim_{s\to 0}\, 2^{s-1} \pi^s \cdot \frac{\sin(\pi s/2)}{\pi s/2} \cdot \Gamma(1-s) \cdot s\zeta(1-s) = 2^{-1} \pi^0 \cdot 1 \cdot \Gamma(1) \cdot (-1) = -\frac{1}{2}.$$
But how does the last term, $$s\zeta(1-s)=$$ Equal -1? Which definition is being used here? How does 0 times the zeta function give -1? The original answer was given at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1751998/1277963

If $f$ is a meromorphic function with a simple pole at $z = z_0$, then $\lim_{z \to 0} zf(z + z_0)$ is the residue of $f$ at $z_0$.

Welcome to MSE. Please, use MathJax also in the title.

We might hope that taking $s \zeta(1 - s)$ and plugging in $s = 0$ would give $0 \cdot \zeta(1)$ and that this would make sense. But the problem is that $\zeta(1) = \infty$ and we cannot make sense of $0 \cdot \infty$.
What's really happening is that in a neighborhood of $1$, we can write
$$ \zeta(s) = \frac{1}{s - 1} + \gamma + (\text{higher order terms}). $$
This is the Laurent expansion of $\zeta$ around $s = 1$. It's very well known and various proofs appear elsewhere on MathSE. Thus
$$ \zeta(1 - s) = \frac{-1}{s} + \gamma + (\text{higher order terms}). $$
We now see that the function $s \zeta(1-s)$ has the local expansion
$$ s \zeta(1-s) = -1 + s\gamma + s\cdot(\mathrm{higher order terms}), $$
and it does make sense to see what happens at $s = 1$ here: it gives $-1$. (Or equivalently, it makes sense to take $s \to 1$ here).
For what it's worth, I'll note that there is another confusing part in the limit that you give: the term $\sin(\pi s / 2)$ is $0$ at $s = 0$, but $\frac{1}{\pi s / 2}$ is $\infty$ at $s = 0$. Similar analysis is required there to make sense of evaluating this function at $s = 0$. The analogous statement as above would be to note that $\sin(x) = x - x^3/6 + \cdots$, so
$$ \frac{\sin x}{x} = 1 - x^2/6 + (\mathrm{higher order terms}), $$
so that as $x \to 0$ we find $\frac{\sin x}{x} \to 1$.

Much of the notation in analytic number theory is overburdened and implicit, especially in connection with analytic and meromorphic continuation. The domains of these functions are left implicit. A good rule of thumb is that analytic number theorists are lazy and intend everything to mean the nicest meromorphic function that agrees with the given function.
For example, when a number theorist writes $g(s) = \sin(s)/s$, they probably (but implicitly) mean a function holomorphic on all of $\mathbb{C}$ that takes the value $1$ at $s = 0$. And they  would happily write $g(0) = 1$, even though it "looks" like this says $\sin(0) / 0 = 1$. This can be annoying.
And I've definitely done this in my own papers too.
